# Image is not reflecting in frontend

Tags: java, angularjs, eclipse

I have been doing this since two days still not found any solution ,
I am uploading image in my images folder of eclipse workspace, the problem occurs when image is first time uploaded then it requires to refresh images folder in workspace and then empty cache reload after that it works fine

This is my html

```
</div><img ng-src="{{image}}"  alt="image caption"  ngf-src="imagePath" style="height: 150px;width: 150px;margin: 10px;" ng-show="imagevisible"></div>
```

and this is my controller

```
 $scope.uploadFiles = function(file) {
    debugger;
    $scope.fileObj = file;

    $scope.fileName = $scope.fileObj.name;
    console.log($scope.fileObj.name);
    }
$scope.submit=function(){
Upload.upload({
        //method  : 'POST',
          url     : '/WarehouseMgmt/material/add_mtr',
          data    : {
                        model : $scope.NewMtr,
                        file : $scope.fileObj
                    },
        //  headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}

         }).then(function(response){
             debugger;       
             //$mdDialog.cancel();

             $scope.showAddMtrlToast();
             $window.location.href="#!/Material/"
             $route.reload();
         },function(response){
                debugger;
                console.log(response.status);               
                if(response.status==500){
                    $scope.showMtrlExistToast();
                }
            });
    };
}
```

and my java controller method which upload Image

```
public String uploadMaterialImage(MultipartFile fileObj) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    String filename = "views.properties";
    InputStream input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);

    if (input == null) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find " + filename);
        return "";
    }

    try {
        properties.load(input);
         pathSave = properties.getProperty("saveImagePath");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    String filePath="";     
    if(!fileObj.isEmpty())
    {
    try {
        System.out.println("inside this serviceImoplMethod!");
        byte[] bytes = fileObj.getBytes();
        String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");      
     File dir = new File(pathToSave);
        File dir = new File(pathSave);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();

        File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                + File.separator +fileObj.getOriginalFilename());
        BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
        stream.write(bytes);
        stream.close();

        filePath=serverFile.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("sysout file  parh::" + filePath);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
    }
     return filePath;
    }
return "";
}
```

Please Help !!

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you are using java ee as back end, and deploying it as war/jar file and saving your uploaded image into your project folder then you will need to redeploy your project. Because deployed java project does not redeploy when one of the files changes.
 Just in case try to save your uploaded images to another folder not your projects.

Comment: Thank you for your suggetion and i just tried it but it didn't work